# Writing files to multiple places in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a script in PHP which takes a bunch of information from a form and writes to to a file. Is it possible to write this file to multiple paths/locations without copying all of the additional code?

Comment: Isn't that what functions are for?

Comment: It sure is possible.

Comment: I suppose I could use a function, its just that I'd be passing a lot of arguments to it (one to represent each field of data collected from the entry).

Comment: you can create an array with all the paths/locations you need and then do a foreach

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/1991715/ - found after "Googling" `write to multiple files php` you can further your research from there. Also http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/11188.htm seems promising.

Comment: Huh, I did do some searching. Should have filtered the results using site:stackoverflow.com. Thanks Fred.

Comment: @skeletonne, you could even pass the whole $_POST array to the function if that's your problem (then you can just copy your current code to the function, while replacing $_POST with the variable you use in the function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create an array with all the paths/locations you need and then do a foreach:

```
$locations = Array("/path/1", "/path/2", ...);

foreach($locations as $location) {
 file_put_contents($file, $location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function with a parameters for the location and file, which saves the file to the given location.
2. Use as many times and for many locations as needed.

Example:

```
function save_file($file, $location) {

  ...

  //do something here

  ...

  file_put_contents($file, $location);

}
```